# Is it possible to find out whether two pairs of concealed numbers have at least one number in common by applying a single test on each of the 2 pairs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Two friends, each has one box, and each box conceals two balls carrying 2 unique natural numbers. The two friends need to know whether they have at least one number in common. While not allowed to divulge their numbers to one another, they are allowed to come up with **ONE** equation/formula and apply it on both boxes, then compare the results. That is, friend-A has 2 balls carrying the numbers {n, m} and applies the formula by plugging in his two numbers, then shares the result he gets with friend-B. Similarly, Friend-B plugs his numbers {x, y} into the very same formula, then they compare the results and judge whether they have one number in common based on that. Using the formula is like a ticket, used once for each person and can't be trial and error.

Is it possible for them to find out whether there exists k $\in$ {n, m} and k $\in$ {x, y} such that k is a natural number, while sticking to these rules?

Comment: Yes, or at least whether $\{n,m\} = \{x,y\}$.  What have you tried yourself?

Comment: By "compare the results" are you saying each can see the result of the full function?  Or just they can tell if their two functions *agree*?

Comment: The functions can give any result, a bool like true or false, or get the same output that tells there is a number in common, like another pair or a just one number.

Comment: So imagine $f(n,m) = 17$ and $f(x,y) = 92$.  That *could* mean that $n = y$.  Is that allowed?

Comment: Assumed that you intend that one of $m,n$ = one of $x,y$.  Suppose that you form a polynomial $f(t)$.  Further suppose that that polynomial is *based* on the known values of $x,y$.  Is it permissible to ask whether $f(x)\times f(y) = f(m) \times f(n)$?  If so, there is an *obvious* answer.

Comment: Oh... must the function be determined *before* anyone opens a box?

Comment: @user2661923 - Yes, this is exactly what I need. Could you provide it?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - No, each can open his/her box, but can't share it with they other.

Comment: Based on your comment to my answer, I have deleted my answer.

Comment: Please define carefully what they can and cannot do.  One approach would be for each to compute the Cantor pairing function of their two values.  One can derive both values from that, then check if there is any match.  Does that violate disclosing their numbers?  What calculations are they allowed to do?  If you don't specify it, we can't answer.

Comment: It can't be trial and error; they can plug in their values ONCE, each get a result, then compare the results and judge based on that. I'll try to edit the post to accentuate that.

Comment: A small, but incomplete step:  *IF* at least one of your numbers is a prime, then compute $n^m$.  Thanks to the fundamental theorem of mathematics, then one can infer $n$ and $m$ from $n^m$.  IF there are no primes, then it will be more complex...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - Yes, f(n, m) = 17, f(x, y) = 92, then somehow you use the results to conclude that there is a number in common, is allowed. I don't see how, but the approach is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Try $f(x,y)=2^{\min\{x,y\}} 3^{\max\{x,y\}} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Alice (with $\{m,n\}$) should compute:  ${\rm Pri}[n]^{{\rm Pri}[m]}$, where ${\rm Pri}[n]$ is the $n$th prime.  For example ${\rm Pri}[4] = 7$, ${\rm Pri}[20] = 71$.  This is implemented in *Mathematica* by `Prime[n]`.  So if Alice has $\{ 4,6 \}$ her function will produce $7^{16} = 33232930569601$.

Bob (with $\{ x, y \}$) should do likewise.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Mathematics (unique prime factorization), one can recover *both* unknown or secret values.  For Alice, `FactorInteger[33232930569601]` gives {{7,16}}.  And likewise for Bob.

It is then a trivial matter to compute if they share a secret number (or both secret numbers), and what its value is.